# Update azure stream analytics query in powershell by passing command line parameter instead of specifying it in .json file

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am updating azure stream analytics query using powershell by following command.

```
New-AzureRMStreamAnalyticsTransformation -ResourceGroupName StreamAnalytics-Default-Central-US –File "C:\Transformation.json" –JobName StreamingJob –Name StreamingJobTransform -Force
```

For that i have to pass stream analytics query in .json file and that .json file contains

```
"properties":{    
  "streamingUnits":1,  
  "query":"select * from MyEventHubSource"
 }
```

So my question is instead of passing query in .json file is there any way to specify query in command line argument? i do not find any way to do so in Microsoft document.

Answer (score 0):

ARM resource updates should be specified in a file, it is not possible to pass it as a command line argument. If it is important, you can perhaps create a ps1 file that creates a temporary file from command line argument and calls the Azure cmdlet.